# Understanding threads and synchronization on a class that spawns the thread

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronization

Ok, so can some one explain to me the gap in my knowledge here?

Initially the example below was trying to synchronize an instance method, but then realised that I spawn a new instance and therefore a lock wouldn't happen.

So I decided to make a lock on a static method of the class in the hope that the thread would then run in order but still no luck. Can any explain the error of my ways? ( Bear with me there are probably better ways to do this its just getting the understanding right, I'm a PHP developer going into Java, I love it - but I'm only 2 days in ;-) )

So at this time the numbers print out in a random order.

Class 1

```
package learningjava;


public class LearningJava {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      ThreadCaller ob1 = new ThreadCaller("This is a test string 1");
      ThreadCaller ob2 = new ThreadCaller("This is a test string 2");
      ThreadCaller ob3 = new ThreadCaller("This is a test string 3");
      ThreadCaller ob4 = new ThreadCaller("This is a test string 4");
      ThreadCaller ob5 = new ThreadCaller("This is a test string 5");

      try {

           ob1.t.join();
           ob2.t.join();
           ob3.t.join();
           ob4.t.join();
           ob5.t.join();

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {

          System.out.println(e);

      }

    }    

}
```

Class 2

```
package learningjava;

public class ThreadCaller implements Runnable {

    private String message;
    public Thread t;

    public ThreadCaller(String text) {
        message = text;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public static synchronized void echo(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }


    public void run() {
            ThreadCaller.echo(this.message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can any explain the error of my ways?

Basically, you're expecting ordering which simply isn't guaranteed. You're calling `start()` on lots of threads in succession... there's no guarantee about which one will actually start executing first. The fact that you've got a static synchronized method just means that only one thread will be executing that method at a time - it doesn't guarantee anything about ordering.

Imagine you have a running track with a one-lane gate 100m down the track. You start the race - which runner will reach the gate first?

Fortunately, this isn't usually a problem - if it's worth starting multiple threads to do something, you *usually* don't care about the order in which they execute. If you do, it's time to re-examine your design.

Comment: Bosh! Thank you. My fault for not reading the book properly! Feel quite stupid now :-D

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling of threads is not predictable.

What you're trying to do beats the purpose of it in a way, doesn't it?

If you want order, either make your execution sequential or invoke them with [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

Comment: Thank you, just pipped to the post!

Answer (score 0):

Ordering can not be performed in this way because  you have started all threads before joining them.

You can maintain ordering either use [ExecurorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29)  and make pool of one thread then in a loop pass one by one thread to pool and execute it.

Other way in your code don't start the thread in `Runnable` , start it in `LearningJave` and join it just after starting one by one.

```
Thread t1=new Thread(ob1);
   t1.start();
   t1.join();

   Thread t2=new Thread(ob2);
   t2.start();
   t2.join();
 ----
 -----
```